# Type is missing the following properties from type 'Schema<any, Model<any,any,any,any>, {}, {}>': add, childSchemas, clearIndexes, clone, and 37 more

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a Mongoose on TypeScript, and it worked without interfaces and types defining, but when I decided to define types, the madness started. I've watched tons of manuals and topics and found nobody with a similar problem. I tried to define a model strictly by the manual, but I'm getting an error. Here's my model file:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

const GeoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point',
        enum: ['Point'],
    },
    coordinates: {
        type: [Number, Number],
        index: '2dsphere',
    },
});

interface postInterface extends mongoose.Document {
    shortId: string;
    createdBy: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    tags: string[];
    location: {};
    images: string[];
    contacts: {
        email: Boolean;
        wa: Boolean;
        phone: Boolean;
    };
    type: 'available' | 'wanted';
    is_moderated: Boolean;
}

export const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        shortId: {
            type: String,
            index: true,
            default: () => nanoid(),
        },
        createdBy: {
            type: String,
            index: true,
        },
        title: String,
        description: String,
        tags: [String],
        location: GeoSchema,
        images: [String],
        contacts: {
            email: Boolean,
            wa: Boolean,
            phone: Boolean,
        },
        type: { type: String, enum: ['available', 'wanted'] },
        is_moderated: Boolean,
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

export const Post = mongoose.model<postInterface>('Post', PostSchema);
```

When I import it into another file, on the line

```
return Post.create(post)
```

the linter gives me the error:

```
Type 'postInterface & { _id: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Schema<any, Model<any, any, any, any>, {}, {}>': add, childSchemas, clearIndexes, clone, and 37 more.ts(2740)
```

I googled examples of typescript model defining, and it looks like something that works for others doesn't work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

Man, it was so obvious! The file where I imported the model looks like this:

```
import { Post, PostSchema } from '../models/post.model';
export class PostService {
    async createPost(post: any): Promise<typeof PostSchema | null> {
        return Post.create(post);
    }

    async getPostById(shortId: string): Promise<typeof PostSchema | null> {
        return Post.findOne({ shortId });
    }
}
```

So the thing was in `Promise<typeof PostSchema | null>`. When I changed the code to this, the error was gone:

```
import { Post, postInterface } from '../models/post.model';
export class PostService {
    async createPost(post: any): Promise<postInterface | null> {
        return Post.create(post);
    }

    async getPostById(shortId: string): Promise<postInterface | null> {
        return Post.findOne({ shortId });
    }
}
```

Thanks to @lpizzinidev for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: Can you post the full code of the function where you are calling the `return Post.create(post)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, it was so obvious! The file where I imported the model looks like this:

```
import { Post, PostSchema } from '../models/post.model';
export class PostService {
    async createPost(post: any): Promise<typeof PostSchema | null> {
        return Post.create(post);
    }

    async getPostById(shortId: string): Promise<typeof PostSchema | null> {
        return Post.findOne({ shortId });
    }
}
```

So the thing was in `Promise<typeof PostSchema | null>`. When I changed the code to this, the error was gone:

```
import { Post, postInterface } from '../models/post.model';
export class PostService {
    async createPost(post: any): Promise<postInterface | null> {
        return Post.create(post);
    }

    async getPostById(shortId: string): Promise<postInterface | null> {
        return Post.findOne({ shortId });
    }
}
```

Thanks to @lpizzinidev for pushing me in the right direction!